# How to power a dc fan (4wire)

Tags: dc, fan

I have intel dc 12v cpu fan (removed from a computer) that has 4 wires (Black Yellow Green Blue)
(Model E97379)
[Photo- http://www.filetolink.com/c50ea25682 ]

I want to power it by ac to dc 12v adapter.

What wires i should connect to my adapter ?

Comment: Can you find a datasheet link for the fan and edit the link into your question?

Comment: @ghost: when we ask for a link we mean add a hyperlink to the datasheet on the manufacturer's or supplier's website, not a file download which may contain a virus. Make it easy for your readers to help you. The datasheet will contain all the technical information including the pinout.

Comment: And same google results show a current rating of 0.17A or 0.20A. Make sure the 12v adapter can at least provide more than that.

Comment: Okay i searched. I should give power to GND and +12v ends. Should i need to do anything with other two wires (signal & pwm) ?

Comment: It is enough. The fan will work.
https://www.glkinst.com/cables/cable_pics/4_Wire_PWM_Spec.pdf

Comment: @ghost21blade - It isn't clear why you are trying to delete / deface your question from 3 years ago. However for the reason you have discovered, you are not able to delete it. You will find more help (and some alternatives) in [this article](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) from the [help]. Please stop trying to vandalise the answer here as well. There is value in the answer for other people in future - which is the whole point of Stack Exchange. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The wires are as follows:

```
Black - GND
Yellow - +12V
Green - O/C tachometer output
Blue - PWM input
```

If you just want the fan to spin at maximum speed, connect the black and yellow to your 12V power supply, and leave the other two unconnected.